# Removing required password to used Terminator terminal package

Tags: command-line, terminator

Every time I open a Terminator terminal window it prompts me for a password to perform administrative tasks. Is there a config file I can edit to prevent it from doing this? I know from having used the default Ubuntu terminal the damage I can cause from the terminal and I don't need the reminder each time and to be forced to type my password.

Comment: You don't want the password prompt just to run Terminator? Or to run any commands inside a terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bad, but if you want to do it go to a terminal and..

```
sudo visudo
```

Add this where username is your username. Then save/exit.

```
username ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/share/terminator
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are opening a terminal with admin rights, instead of a standard terminal. You should only use this if you need to perform tasks that require this level of privilige, e.g. installing or updating software.

If you can't find the regular terminal from the menu, then pressing CTRL + ALT + T will give you a terminal with your normal user priviliges without asking for your password.

Comment: Thank you for your advice but i really like the functionality of the Terminator terminal. Is there a config file i could chamge so it doesnt keep trying to force admin rights on me?

Comment: The config file for Terminator is  `~/.config/terminator/config` and a full description of it is available on [Ubuntu Manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man5/terminator_config.5.html). However I can't see any mention of running as root, or not, which makes me think that it might be the the way you are laumching it that causes the password prompt. 
How are you starting Terminator?
What happens if you open a standard terminal (CTRL+ALT+T) and type `terminator`? Does it still ask for the password?

Comment: This is the problem I'm having right now. Seems to have appeared after I tried "installing" ELementary OS on top of Ubuntu, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to dig up an old question.

In my case, this turned out to be due to an errant `sudo` command being run from my `~/.bashrc`. Removing the `sudo` command did the trick :)